# localStorage.clear(); not working in Ember.js, at least not with an ajax call

Tags: ember.js, local-storage

## Please see follow-up question <strike>[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18117734/733034)</strike> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18135004/733034) where it gets to the meat of the problem.

I am making an ajax call that reloads the data in the local storage of an Ember App. I am calling `localStorage.clear();` right before the ajax call. However, after the ajax call, nothing is cleared!

The printout `localStorage.getItem("model-emberjs")` right after the clear() and is null as expected. 
The printout `localStorage.getItem("model-emberjs")` right after the ajax call that follows has everything from before.

I'm using the LS adapter.

Do you have any idea why?

---

P.S. I don't know how to make ajax call work in jsbin so sorry no live example.

Comment: Is it possible the AJAX is cached? Did you verify it works in the network tab?

Answer (score 0):

As @Benjamin already mentioned I also believe you have a caching problem. If you are using chrome try to disable the cache while developing by bringing up the extra settings dialog:

[image]

And then enable "Disable cache":

[image]

Now try again to call `localStorage.clear()` it should work this time.

Hope it helps.